# Images not showing on Wordpress website after migrating to hosting provider

Tags: wordpress

I recently migrated my website to a hosting provider from localhost and some of the "Featured Images" on the some pages are not showing up. I went to the Chrome Console on the computer that was having this problem and saw this error:[image]

[image: Screenshots]

I see that Wordpress is trying to load the image from Localhost instead of the website. My siteurl and home options are set correctly. I have already tried deleting all the plugins but that didn't help. I also tried recreating the page on the server itself and it did not help. Can you please help?

Edit: I do see the images in the Media Library, but don't see them on the page when it loads.

Comment: The proper way to call the post thumbnail is `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`. That might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your db with plugin [WP Migrate DB](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/)

Answer (score 0):

Upload a new site to hosting, after local development, as follows:

1. Copy the site folder from the local server to another location.
2. Export the Database to the copied folder with the site.
3. Using the editor (the normal editor should have a search-replacement), replace all occurrences of `'localhost/your_folder'` on the site and in the database on `'yoursite.com'`
4. Upload the site and the database to the server, respectively.

Comment: Thank you! This would also have probably worked, but the first suggestion with the plugin was the one I tried. Thanks for the suggestion.